# pycrypto massup when install with crypto on mac

Tags: python, macos, centos, pip, pycrypto

I am trying to install [`crypto`](https://pypi.org/project/crypto/) and [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) in same virtual environment.

```
[root@jnkslave01 tmp]# virtualenv test_pycrypto
New python executable in /root/tmp/test_pycrypto/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[root@jnkslave01 tmp]# source test_pycrypto/bin/activate
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]# pip install crypto==1.4.1 pycrypto==2.6.1 
Collecting crypto==1.4.1
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading https://pypi.storage.rackspace.com/packages/crypto-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycrypto==2.6.1
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/root/tmp/test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Requirement already satisfied: Naked in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: shellescape in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from requests->Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from requests->Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from requests->Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in ./test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from requests->Naked->crypto==1.4.1)
Installing collected packages: crypto, pycrypto
Successfully installed crypto-1.4.1 pycrypto-2.6.1
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]# python -c "from Crypto import Random"
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]#
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Its working fine in `CentOS 6.9` but when I try to do that in my Mac. It gives error.

```
(test_pycrypto) ABCDEFG:~ myuser$ python -c "from Crypto import Random"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

When I check, what is the difference between these 2 setups, I found in `Mac` it install `Crypto` in `crypto` directory in `site-packages`

**On Mac**

```
(test_pycrypto) ABCDEFG:~ myuser$ ls test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/crypto/
Cipher          PublicKey       Signature       __init__.pyc        decryptoapp.py      pct_warnings.py     settings.pyc
Hash            Random          Util            app.py          decryptoapp.pyc     pct_warnings.pyc
Protocol        SelfTest        __init__.py     app.pyc         library         settings.py
(test_pycrypto) ABCDEFG:~ myuser$ ls test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/
Cipher          PublicKey       Signature       __init__.pyc        decryptoapp.py      pct_warnings.py     settings.pyc
Hash            Random          Util            app.py          decryptoapp.pyc     pct_warnings.pyc
Protocol        SelfTest        __init__.py     app.pyc         library         settings.py
```

On Mac, it somehow combine both packages and put same content in both directory, while on `CentOS` it has both directory with different content.

**On CentOS**

```
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]# ls test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/crypto
app.py  app.pyc  decryptoapp.py  decryptoapp.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  library  settings.py  settings.pyc
(test_pycrypto) [root@jnkslave01 tmp]# ls test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/
Cipher  Hash  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  pct_warnings.py  pct_warnings.pyc  Protocol  PublicKey  Random  SelfTest  Signature  Util
```

I ran same command on both setup, also tried with `Python 3`, it has same problem.

What I am doing wrong on Mac, which cause this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system of Mac OS X is case insensitive, it doesn't distinguish `Crypto` and `crypto`. You cannot install both into the same virtual environment. Separate them.

Comment: one more question, if mac cant distinguish, then when I do `from Crypto import Random` it should find in `test_pycrypto/lib/python2.6/site-packages/crypto/` because this directory has `Random` package in it.

Comment: Create or mount case-sensitive filesystem. Create a new case-sensitive HFS with command [`newfs_hfs -s`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/newfs_hfs.8.html) (do not experiment on a live system and always make backup!) Or mount case-sensitive filesystem from an external drive or over the net.

Comment: I don't know how exactly Python behaves on a case-insensitive filesystem. It could be that Python distinguish `crypto` from `Crypto` and cannot find `Crypto` if `crypto` has been installed.

Comment: Experimenting with filesystems is rather hard, perhaps you could manipulate one of the modules — for example, install `crypto`, rename its directory and rewrite the code — fix `import crypto` and `from crypto import…`. After that install `Crypto`.