If I install two distribution packages that provide the same import package, which one is imported?
As a quick reminder, a distribution package is what you install through pip. Each distribution package can contain (multiple) import packages which may or may not have the same name. For example the distribution package scikit-learn provides the import package sklearn.
Now, if I install two distribution packages through pip, but both distribution packages offer an import package with the same name, which will get imported?
For example suppose I install distribution packages a and b, but both packages offer an import package foo. When I write import foo, which import package will I get?

All imports will be done in order according to sys.path. The import details can be observed with the -v command line argument or the interpreter.

@KlausD. You may assume that both are installed into the same directory, so sys.path does not offer any 'tiebreaks'.

Please give an example on how this installation should look like.

@KlausD. Simply pip install a b for two distribution packages a and b that offer the same import package.

You are here for long enough to know how to create a minimal reproducible example.

@KlausD. If you insist, an example is pip install polars-lts-cpu polars-u64-idx which both offer the polars package. I'm interested in a general answer though, not one specifically for these two packages.

@KlausD. Distributions crypto and pycrypto have similar top-level packages: crypto and Crypto. On a case-insensitive filesystem they overwrite each other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629482/pycrypto-massup-when-install-with-crypto-on-mac/50634103

I would have hoped that pip would reject installing packages due to file path collisions, but that seems to not be the case https://discuss.python.org/t/python-module-conflict-discussion/23659 A similar issue can happen in Debian based distributions, typically surrounding virtual packages. In these cases, one usually denotes in the package metadata for A, that it "Conflicts" B, allowing tools like apt-get to reject the install early. Seems like for now, this is undefined behavior, which is extraordinarily depressing for a package manager to have.

I do not believe it is deterministic. If I recall correctly pip will write one import package on disk then overwrite the directory with the other import package. I do not think that this happens in a specific order. I guess it might depend on what the dependency resolution algorithm outputs first, but I am really not sure.
